# how to remove attribute selected from all selected options in select in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

I'm not remove attribute selected from all selected options in jquery.

Please help me.

My html code is :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">
$('#commentform .comment-form-rating input#dap_rating').change(function () {
$('#commentform .comment-form-rating #rating option').on('change',function() {
   alert("nb = "+$(this).find(":selected").length);
});
$("#commentform .comment-form-rating #rating option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
$("#commentform .comment-form-rating #rating option:selected").prop("selected", false);
$("#commentform .comment-form-rating #rating > option:selected").each(function() {
});
$(document.body).on('change', '#commentform .comment-form-rating #rating', function () {
var c = $('#commentform .comment-form-rating #rating').filter((i, s) => $(s)[0].selectedIndex > 0).length;
console.log(c);
});
$('#mySelect option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
});
</script>
<select name="rating" id="rating" required="" style="display: none;">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">رای دهید</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected">عالی</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">خوب</option>
    <option value="3">متوسط</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">نه خیلی بد</option>
    <option value="1">خیلی بد</option>
</select>
```

and all the top ways not working.

selected options length return only 1.
i'm not to do select all selected options to remove attribute selected.

tank's all.

Comment: When using <script>, you are not supposed to have both a `src` and content. You need to *either* link an external one, *or* use inline code. This should work: `$(function () { $('option').removeAttr('selected'); });`

Comment: Browser will ignore more than one `selected` if the `<select>` isn't `multiple`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `removeAttr()` for all options:

```js
$('#rating option').removeAttr('selected');

console.log($('#rating').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="rating" id="rating" required="">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">رای دهید</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected">عالی</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">خوب</option>
    <option value="3">متوسط</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">نه خیلی بد</option>
    <option value="1">خیلی بد</option>
</select>
```